# OnServerChange event not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

I have the HTML tag select which has the OnServerChange event which is not firing.

HTML:

```
<div class="Column">
 <select runat="server" onserverchange="cboPricePoint_OnServerChange" 
 onchange="GetPPId(this);" datavaluefield="PricePointId" id="cboPricePoint" 
 name="cboPricePoint" class="select">
 </select>
</div>
```

CS:

```
protected void cboPricePoint_OnServerChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

onServerChange event is a server-side event so it can only be fired when the form is submitted.
So `onChange` event, you need to submit the form which contains this `select` then onserverchange event will be happened.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking into the problem in the wrong approach.

First, this is not JavaScript related. JavaScript has no onServerChanged event/attribute. So you cannot expect JavaScript to do that.

Two Things:

- Either you can use .net dropdownlist object instead of HTML select element.
- Submit the form to server onchange of select.

Comment: Thanks for help. The reason I included JS is because I have both onchange client event and onserverchange server side event. I am able to trigger onchange event but i'm not able to trigger onserverchange server event. I just wanted to see if i'm doing it the wrong way.