# Unable to trigger onchange event from select tag in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I want to change the textboxes that should be displayed based on accountType the user selects. However, the onchange event attached to select is not getting triggered. Any heads up?

This is the select tag.

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="color:black">
    <select name="accountTypes" id="accountTypes" runat="server" onchange="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" onserverchange="accountType_Changed">
            <option value="customer">Customer</option>
            <option value="pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>
            <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The `accountType_Changed` function is:

```
void accountType_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cnic.Text = accountTypes.SelectedItem.Value;//or accountTypes.SelectedItem.Text
}
```

**Edit:**
Based on the solution proposed by @mahesh_b, following edits were made that fixed the problem:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.accountTypes.Attributes.Add("onchange", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.accountTypes, this.accountTypes.ID));
}

protected void accountType_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cnic.Text = "Working!!!"; //accountTypes.SelectedItem.Value;//or accountTypes.SelectedItem.Text
}
```

**Edit 2: Layout Rendering Issue after adding partial refresh**

Login.aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="scriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <section class="login_part section_padding ">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="login_part_text text-center">
                    <div class="login_part_text_iner">
                        <h2>New to PHS?</h2>

                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="column col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" runat="server">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="column col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" runat="server">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                               </div>    

                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="cnic" placeholder="CNIC" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="pass" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="color:black">
                            <select name="accountTypes" id="accountTypes" runat="server" onchange="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" onserverchange="accountType_Changed">
                              <option value="customer">Customer</option>
                              <option value="pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>
                              <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <br /><br />
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="taxNo" placeholder="Tax No" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="pName" placeholder="Pharmacy Name" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="pAddress" placeholder="Pharmacy Address" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="cAddress" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="docID" placeholder="Doctor Id" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="experience" placeholder="Experience (Years)" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="expertise" placeholder="Expertise (Specialization)" class="form-control" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <br />
                        <p>Create an account today and avail the best deals on medics.</p>      
                        <asp:Button ID="registerButton" class="btn_3" runat="server" width="50%" Text="Create Account" OnClick="createAccount_Clicked"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="login_part_form">
                    <div class="login_part_form_iner">
                        <h3>Welcome Back ! <br>
                            Please Sign in now</h3>
                        <form class="row contact_form" action="#" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value=""
                                    placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value=""
                                    placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">

                                <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn_3">
                                    log in
                                </button>
                                <a class="lost_pass" href="#">forget password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

These images show the original layout of select and what gets loaded after I change the value:

Original:
[image: Original Layout]

This is what gets loaded after changing the value in accountType:

[image: Modified]

How can I get to keep my original layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML controls use the server events, in your case [`OnServerChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.onserverchange?view=netframework-4.8) event. In order the serverchange event to fire you have to explicitly submit the form or do a postback on `onchange` event. You can do this with below two options -

1. Submit the form on `onchange` event from client side:

> ```
> <select name="accountTypes" id="accountTypes" runat="server" 
> onchange="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" onserverchange="accountType_Changed">
> ```

2. Use the [GetPostBackEventReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference?view=netframework-4.8) method from server side:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {      
       this.accountTypes.Attributes.Add("onchange", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.accountTypes, this.accountTypes.ID));

   }
   ```

*You may have to also change the method signature to-*

```
    protected void accountType_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Refer these threads to understand more on the same -

[How to make HtmlSelect Control with OnChange event to trigger C# code behind function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395458/how-to-make-htmlselect-control-with-onchange-event-to-trigger-c-sharp-code-behin)

[OnServerChange event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618683/onserverchange-event-not-firing)

If your requirement can fit with changing to ASP.NET Drop down list then you can follow which [Selim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166389/unable-to-trigger-onchange-event-from-select-tag-in-asp-net/62168011#62168011) mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Thank You very much. The trigger is now getting fired. One small issue is that upon executing the function, the webpage resets the scrolling. I read that it occurs due to href="#". But in the function I have not used this tag. Any work around for that would be great.

Comment: This answer fits to what your original question was related to HTML select. But you have edited that question not sure why as others may not see this as invalid answer! Keep your original question along with updated one with proper description!

Comment: For scrolling this may help -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134963/prevent-page-scrolling-after-postback

Comment: I realized that changing every time the value in accountType is changed, the page is getting refreshed. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Raza..that is normal behavior with aspx controls. You may have to check partial page updates with update panels-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax

Comment: I followed the guide you attached. I added the UpdatePanel and the ScriptManager and I finally got partial refresh enabled on my webpage. But there is a caveat though. For some reason the layout for select isn't loading. It has the ID "accountTypes". I added the modifications in form of edit. Kindly have a look on it please. Thank You

Comment: This seems to be different question against original intnded ask!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ASP.NET Dropdownlist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.8) with using `AutoPostBack=true` to trigger `OnChange` event:

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="color:black">
    <asp:DropDownList id="accountTypes" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="accountType_Changed" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Value="account_type">Account Type</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="customer"> Customer </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="pharmacy"> Pharmacy </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="doctor"> Doctor </asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
 </div>
```

And server side `accountType_Changed` would be like this:

```
void accountType_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    username.Text = accountTypes.SelectedItem.Value;//or accountTypes.SelectedItem.Text
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. But now I'm getting compilation error: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'login_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'accountType_Changed' and no accessible extension method 'accountType_Changed' accepting a first argument of type 'login_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Not sure why it is occurring. I have modified the question with the proposed modification.

Comment: Could you try to add `Protected` and try again?